# Does Tridion 2013 SP1 and RTF fields use WCAG 2.0 or WCAG 1.0?

Tags: 2013, rtf

We are introducing Accessibility to our web implementation and, in order to be complete, we would like to use it in our Tridion  RTF fields.

We are using WCAG 2.0. What is Tridion 2013 SP1 using on its validation?

NOTE: If you have any experience on RTF and WCAG, perhaps you would like to share it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this website: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/from10/diff.php, WCAG 2.0 differs from 1.0 primarily in how each acceptance criteria is explained when a test fails to meet a criteria (in WCAG 2.0 is much more granular/specific than 1.0), and I quote: "The fundamental issues of Web accessibility are the same, though there are some differences in the organization and requirements between WCAG 1.0 and WCAG 2.0."

So for Web, as long as the system enforces WCAG at a given priority level, it seems to be irrelevant whether it's WCAG 1.0 or WCAG 2.0 because the version differences are in the way issues are organized when reported, not enforced by the system (and Tridion is not a WCAG testing system). So for RTFs, Tridion will give you WCAG HTML produced by the WYSIWYG; while anything on Content Delivery is your custom front-end code, which is outside of Tridion's enforcement jurisdiction.